# How to get the url where an entity is flagged

Tags: 7, flags

How is it possible to get the URL of the content **where the user was** when s/he flagged an entity? I have content in a view in which I have the links to flag the entities so the URL where the entity is flagged is not the one of the entity itself as available in `$account`

I've tried this snippet to get the `arg()` of the page but as I thought, the `arg()` is related to the flagged entity.

```
function MYMODULE_flag($flag, $entity_id, $account, $flagging) {
  if ($entity_id->fid == FID && $flag == "flag"){
    dpm(arg());
    }
}
```

Comment: Without altering the flag module I'm pretty sure that isn't possible. At a pinch you could try inspecting `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']`, but that's not a bulletproof method by any stretch

Comment: you should be able to set the flag link type to a javascript toggle. Thus, you wouldn't be leaving your views page to actually do the flagging when clicking on it and arg() should then be that of the views page. Of course, if you want to end up on the flagged content (user I am assuming given $account mentioned above) you could do some fancy drupal_goto() in your module's flag hook if arg() was the view page :)

Comment: @Clive `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` appears to be empty when using the `dpm()` in the above function...

Comment: I guess your flag uses AJAX then?

Comment: Yes! I am using flag through AJAX -- I was planning to answer @Jimajamma in this answer as well!

Comment: Blasted Americanisation of the wonderful English language - PHP uses `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` (one 'r') instead of the (IMHO) correct spelling. But that header is optional and some browsers simply won't send it. Without changing the flag module's JS to pass back the current URL I can't think of a way around this